# ecs cloudformation - running into "CannotPullContainerError"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

i try to ramp up some cloudformation knowledge and playing around with some yaml files. No i stuck for a few hours with Docker and Fargate. The Docker Container is starting on a Fargate Instance but it cant pull the "httpd:latest" image from Dockerhub. The error is:

CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I think ive some erros on the VPC/SecurityGroup or InternetGateway but i cant find it. Hope somebody can help me...

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
#
# PARAMETERS?
#
Parameters:
  AppSlug:
    Type: String
    Default: "polaris_55"
#
#
# Mappings ?
#
#
Mappings:
 Config:  
  Network:
    CidrVpc: '10.0.0.0/16'
    CidrSubnetAlpha: '10.0.10.0/24'
    CidrSubnetBeta: '10.0.20.0/24'
    CidrSubnetGamma: '10.0.30.0/24'
#
#
# Resources ?
#
#
Resources:
  #
  # Network
  #
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties: 
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [ Config, Network, CidrVpc ]
      EnableDnsHostnames: "false"
      EnableDnsSupport: "false"
      InstanceTenancy: "default"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_vpc"
  SubnetAlpha:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [ Config, Network, CidrSubnetAlpha ]
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}a"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_alpha"
  SubnetBeta:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [ Config, Network, CidrSubnetBeta ]
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}b"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_beta"
  SubnetGamma:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [ Config, Network, CidrSubnetGamma ]
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}c"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_gamma"
  # GATEWAY FÜR VPC
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  GatewayAttachement:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: GatewayAttachement
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref 'PublicRouteTable'
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      GatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
  PublicSubnetAlpha:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAlpha
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetBeta:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBeta
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetGamma:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetGamma
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  #
  # ECS
  #
  EcsCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties: 
      ClusterName: !Sub "${AppSlug}_ecs"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_ecs"
  #
  # Apache Container
  # 
  TaskApache: 
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties: 
      ContainerDefinitions: 
        - Name: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_container"
          Image: "httpd:latest"
          PortMappings: 
            - ContainerPort: 80
              HostPort: 80
              Protocol: "tcp"
      Cpu: "256"
      Memory: "512"
      RequiresCompatibilities: 
        - "FARGATE"
      NetworkMode: "awsvpc"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_task"
  # ECS Service für Apache
  ServiceApache:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties: 
      Cluster: !Ref EcsCluster
      #DeploymentController: 
      #  Type: "CODE_DEPLOY"
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: "FARGATE"
      #LoadBalancers: 
      #  - LoadBalancer
      NetworkConfiguration: 
         AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: "ENABLED"
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecurityApache
          Subnets: 
            - !Ref SubnetAlpha
            - !Ref SubnetBeta
            - !Ref SubnetGamma
      # PropagateTags: "TASK_DEFINITION"
      SchedulingStrategy: "REPLICA"
      ServiceName: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_service"
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskApache
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_service"
  # Security Group für den Apache
  SecurityApache:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_security"
      GroupName: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_security"
      # Inbound Rules für Apache
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - Description: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_security_ingress"
          IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}_apache_security"
```

Comment: Can you enable DNShostnames and DNSsupport and try again?

Comment: like marcin said above,try enabling "EnableDnsSupport" for the dns resolutions to work. here is the quote from aws "Indicates whether the DNS resolution is supported. If this attribute is false, the Amazon Route 53 Resolver server that resolves public DNS hostnames to IP addresses is not enabled" reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support

Comment: Thx... thats it...